# How many games played in the competition? APMOPS (SMOPS)

Tags: contest-math

2017 schools participated in a big inter-school chess competition. Each school sent 2 participants.
The rules of the competition were:
i) Participants do not compete with each other for more than 1 game;
ii) Participants from the same school can not compete with each other.
After many rounds of the competition, it was known that every participant had
completed a different number of games except for participants from one of the 2017
schools which we call it School X. How many games had each of these 2 participants from the school X completed?

If there are 2 schools, I can work out that each of the school X participants played 1 game. Two players from another school play 0 and 2 games.
But I can not figure out 2017 schools.

Comment: What if there are 3 schools?

Comment: How many participants are there?   What is the range of number of games played?

Comment: There are 2017*2=4034 participants.  Range: 0 to 4033